# Differentiation of inverse functions using graphs with conditions?

Tags: derivatives, inversive-geometry

I  was trying to differentiate this equation. And I got the answer but it matches none. Any help on how to solve this one. I tried by converting this function to
**$y=tan^{-1}tan{\frac{x}2}  $** and then using condition to differentiate but my answer is not coming. Please help me solve this.The correct answer is option (b) 
Second question is I am startled about how can value of **$ cos{\frac{x}2}  $** & 
**$ sin{\frac{x}2}  $** affect the differentiation.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you did before, by writing the fraction with respect to $k=\tan (x/2)$, we have $$y=\frac{\sqrt{1+2k/(1+k^2)}+\sqrt{1-2k/(1+k^2)}}{\sqrt{1+2k/(1+k^2)}-\sqrt{1-2k/(1+k^2)}}=\frac{|k+1|+|k-1|}{|k+1|-|k-1|}$$ So, if $k-1>0$ which is equivalent to $\sin(x/2)>\cos(x/2)$ we get $$y=\frac{k+1+k-1}{k+1-k+1}=k=\tan(x/2)$$ Now think about this latter one.

Comment: Another one is cot(x/2) . Which is equal to tan((pi/2)-(x/2)) . Am I on the right path right? Thanks and (+1).

Comment: Yes $\cot(x/2)=\tan(\pi/2-x/2)$

Comment: How did you remove the square roots? And converted them into modulus form.

Comment: $\sqrt{1+k^2}\neq 0$ can be factored and then removed.

Comment: Really lovely solution! :D

Comment: Very well done, my friend!

Comment: @BabakS.: Very nice +1!